# Recents on the double click home page

Tags: iphone, ios

Why does the double click home page store recents and how do I delete them?

Comment: Huh? You mean Mobile Safari? which iOS version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It's a new feature for iOS 8.

Disable it in the settings app under Mail, Contacts, Calendars

About 2/3 of the way down the settings (swipe up) you can tap on **Show in App Switcher** and decide if you want either favorites or recents.